Trigger compile errors in constexpr functions
Considering codes below:
#include <cstddef>
#include <stdexcept>

template<size_t N>
class StaticBST {
private:
    struct Node {
        int value;
        Node * left;
        Node * right;

        inline constexpr Node(int value = 0, Node * left = nullptr, Node * right = nullptr) : value(value), left(left), right(right) {}
        inline constexpr void insert(Node * node) {
            if(node->value < value) {
                if(left) {
                    left->insert(node);
                } else {
                    left = node;
                }
            }
            else if(node->value > value) {
                if(right) {
                    right->insert(node);
                } else {
                    right = node;
                }
            }
            else {
                throw std::runtime_error("Duplicate value");
            }
        }
    };

    Node * __root;
    Node __nodes[N];

public:
    inline constexpr StaticBST(const int (&arr)[N]) : __root(), __nodes() {
        __root = __nodes;
        __root->value = arr[0];
        for(size_t i = 1; i < N; i++) {
            __nodes[i].value = arr[i];
            __root->insert(&__nodes[i]);
        }
    }
};

inline constexpr auto bst1 = StaticBST({1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
inline constexpr auto bst2 = StaticBST({1, 1, 3, 4, 5});

class StaticBST helps build a BST at compile time. bst1 will pass compilation but bst2 will meet throw std::runtime_error("Duplicate value"); and raise a compile error.
What I really want is a proper compile error message like static_assert sends rather than this:
./static_bst.hpp:50:23: error: constexpr variable 'bst2' must be initialized by a constant expression
   50 | inline constexpr auto bst2 = StaticBST({1, 1, 3, 4, 5});
      |                       ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./static_bst.hpp:29:17: note: subexpression not valid in a constant expression
   29 |                 throw std::runtime_error("Duplicate value");
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./static_bst.hpp:44:13: note: in call to 'this->__root->insert(&bst2.__nodes[1])'
   44 |             __root->insert(&__nodes[i]);
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./static_bst.hpp:50:30: note: in call to 'StaticBST({1, 1, 3, 4, 5})'
   50 | inline constexpr auto bst2 = StaticBST({1, 1, 3, 4, 5});
      |                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

So is there any way to use static_assert instead of throw? Or is there any API in C++ that can trigger a compile error in such case?
The compilor I'm using is:
clang++ --version
Homebrew clang version 18.1.8
Target: arm64-apple-darwin23.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin

I tried to use this statement to replace the throw statement:
static_assert(value != node.value, "Duplicate value");

But it turned out:
./static_bst.hpp:30:31: error: static assertion expression is not an integral constant expression
   30 |                 static_assert(value != node->value, "");
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

As is known, the arguments of constexpr function is not regarded as constexpr values. By the way, what makes this question different from this is that the arguments of the constructor is a reference of an array (aka. const int (&)[N]), so I don't think it can be easily passed via template parameters.

You made it properly. There is no way to use static_assert because functional parameters are not constexpr. Optionally you can pass node values via template parameters, then static_assert usage is possible. See the duplicated question.

But is it possible to pass a const int (&)[N] via template parameters?
